# Verify that the Developer App certificate is verified on your device

Tags: ios, xcode

We are trying to install our application from Xcode to an iPhone 14 Pro. After building the app, we must go to General -> VPN & Device Management to trust the certificate. Unfortunately, the certificate is not showing on the iPhone, and we can not install the app. Does anyone know how we can solve this problem?
Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Disconnect the device from Xcode, Quite Xcode, and Restart the System if it is not refreshed.

Comment: @Chetu Unfortunately, this does not help. We have restarted all the services, restored the iPhones and reinstalled Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by first cleaning the build folder (Product -> Clean build folder or Command + Shift + Option + K) and then deleting derived data (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache).